# Name second level of nested list in R

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a nested list similar to the following dummy:

```
list1 <- list(1:3, 4:7, 8:10)
list2 <- list(2:5, 4:9, 19:23, 15:18)
list3 <- list(1:5)

nested_list <- list(list1, list2, list3)
names(nested_list) <- c("first", "second", "third")
```

The first level is named, while the second level is not. I would like to assign names to the second level of the list based on the first level names and pos indices, so the structure of this list would look like this:

```
List of 3
 $ first :List of 3
  ..$ first_1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ first_2: int [1:4] 4 5 6 7
  ..$ first_3: int [1:3] 8 9 10
 $ second:List of 4
  ..$ second_1: int [1:4] 2 3 4 5
  ..$ second_2: int [1:6] 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ..$ second_3: int [1:5] 19 20 21 22 23
  ..$ second_4: int [1:4] 15 16 17 18
 $ third :List of 1
  ..$ third_1: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `for` loop?

```r
for (i in seq_along(nested_list)) {
   names(nested_list[[i]]) <- paste(names(nested_list)[i], 
                                    seq_along(nested_list[[i]]), 
                                    sep = "_")
}
```

Comment: Thank you oh wise one.

Comment: Thank you comments are actually deprecated on SO, but you're welcome to click on the check-mark to accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

Alternative option:

```
setNames(lapply(seq_along(nested_list), function(x) { setNames(nested_list[[x]],paste(names(nested_list)[x], 1:length(nested_list[[x]]), sep="_")) }), names(nested_list))
```

Comment: this is nice but may you could add some line breaks?

Answer (score 2):

Using `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
nested_list <- imap(nested_list, ~ setNames(.x, str_c(.y, "_", seq_along(.x))))
```

-output

```
> str(nested_list)
List of 3
 $ first :List of 3
  ..$ first_1: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ first_2: int [1:4] 4 5 6 7
  ..$ first_3: int [1:3] 8 9 10
 $ second:List of 4
  ..$ second_1: int [1:4] 2 3 4 5
  ..$ second_2: int [1:6] 4 5 6 7 8 9
  ..$ second_3: int [1:5] 19 20 21 22 23
  ..$ second_4: int [1:4] 15 16 17 18
 $ third :List of 1
  ..$ third_1: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```